# Change journaltitle to italics in \fullcite

Tags: biblatex, citing, italic

In a document I want to cite a publication with all authors and all text in italics prior to the start of a section. The italics is necessary to visually set it apart from the rest of the text. I put the following lines into my preamble and they do what they should. I am not able to make the name of the journal `\itshape` though. If possible I would also like to remove the word "In:" which is printed in front of the journal title each time.

```
\preto\fullcite{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}}
\preto\fullcite{\AtNextCitekey{\clearfield{url} \clearfield{doi} 
\clearfield{eprint} \clearfield{pages} \clearfield{note}}}
\preto\fullcite{\AtNextCitekey{\normalfont\itshape}} %\sl for slanted
# This next line doesnt work
#\preto\fullcite{\AtNextCitekey{\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\normalfont\itshape{#1}}} %\sl for slanted
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so it is easier to help you. Which citation style are you using?

Comment: Nevermind, i missed a bracked \preto\fullcite{\AtNextCitekey{\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\normalfont\itshape{#1}}}} wokrs

Answer (score 1):

You already found the missing closing bracket in the comments, so here is an alternative approach defining a new command `\itfullcite` whose output is completely in italics. To make sure no switching back occurs, we simply redefine the `biblatex` commands `\mkbibemph` and `\mkbibitalic`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibforceitalic}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \mkbibitalic{%
    \renewrobustcmd*{\mkbibemph}{\@firstofone}%
    \renewrobustcmd*{\mkbibitalic}{\@firstofone}%
    #1%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\itfullcite}[\mkbibforceitalic]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\itfullcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Fullcite in italics and bibliography entry (not in italics)]